# How can I evaluate this integral faster in Mathematica?

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics

I am trying to run this on *Mathematica*, but *Mathematica* does not show anything. Do I need a change of variables? Is there any way to evaluate this?

```
Dist=ExponentialDistribution[1];
pdfH[g] := PDF[Dist, g];

NIntegrate[Exp[-\[Pi]*5*r^2]*Exp[-2*\[Pi]*5*NIntegrate[(NIntegrate[
      1 - Exp[-2*r^(4)*v^(-4)*g]*v, {v, r, 
       Infinity}])*pdfH[g], {g, 0, Infinity}]]*2*\[Pi]*5*r,{r,0,Infinity}]
```

Comment: I get an error that `Integrate[1 - Exp[-2*r^(4)*v^(-4)*g]*v, {v, r, Infinity}]` does not converge on `{r, Infinity}`. Maybe that's causing the problems.

Comment: @mszynisz, If I use NIntegrate instead, is it a right way?

Comment: I don't think it will change much. Oh, shouldn't it say `pdfH[g]` instead of `PDF[g]` under the integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your integral is just not converging. To evaluate this, we can use the nested integrals as such:

```
ClearAll[integral1, integral2, pdfH];
pdfH[g_] := PDF[ExponentialDistribution[1], g];
limit = 50;

(* Calculate first integral analytically *)
integral1[r_, g_] := Evaluate@Integrate[1 - Exp[-2*r^(4)*v^(-4)*g]*v,
  {v, r, limit}, Assumptions -> r > 0];

(* Treat the second integral as nested *)
integral2[r_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(integral1[r, g])*pdfH[g], {g, 0, limit}];

(* Evaluate the final integral *)
NIntegrate[Exp[-\[Pi]*5*r^2]*Exp[-2*\[Pi]*5*integral2[r]]*2*\[Pi]*5*r, {r, 0, limit}]
```

Notice that I have not used `Infinity` as an upper limit, just a number `limit` that we can increase if we want to. However, if you increase `limit`, the final answer also increases drastically. So it seems like your integral does not converge.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. In one literature I found that integral1 can be evaluated by using the change of variable: r^-\[Alpha]-> y. How to do it in Mathematica?

Comment: @Dimitrios Hmm, are you sure you have written the integral correctly? Maybe it should be `(1 - Exp[-2*r^(4)*v^(-4)*g])*v` under the integral?

Comment: you are right, but it is already there! I found the equation here...https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.0516v2.pdf, on page 8 followed by equation 12.

Comment: @Dimitrios Then you can run it analytically: `Integrate[
 Exp[-\[Pi]*5*r^2]*
  Exp[-2*\[Pi]*5*
    Integrate[(Integrate[(1 - Exp[-2*r^(4)*v^(-4)*g])*v, {v, r, 
         Infinity}, Assumptions -> r > 0])*pdfH[g], {g, 0, 
      Infinity}]]*2*\[Pi]*5*r, {r, 0, Infinity}]` which gives `1/(1 + Sqrt[2] ArcTan[Sqrt[2]])`.